# PYSPARK: how to cluster more efficiently?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark

I have the a dataset and I want to cluster it, for example consider the following:

```python
data = array([0.0,0.0, 1.0,1.0, 9.0,8.0, 8.0,9.0]).reshape(4, 2)
```

to cluster it, first I need to train a model:

```python
model = KMeans.train(sc.parallelize(data), 2, maxIterations=10,initializationMode="random",seed=50, initializationSteps=5, epsilon=1e-4)
```

then to find the clusters I have to do the following for each of the arrays in my dataset:

```python
model.predict(array([0.0, 0.0]))
```

my question is that is there any way that I can find the clusters in the training phase?

If I cannot do it using MLlib, do you know any other libraries that can find cluster members faster?

Comment: After a first look it seems this is not accessible API-wise (but i'm not a pyspark user), in contrast to scikit-learn's approach for example. The latter actually makes sense as this information is needed in each iteration. But usually you need many iterations and what you are doing is less than the cost of 1 full iteration, so it won't change much (sklearn max_iter = 300 -> 0.3% of time needed for this step in this case).

Comment: maybe the OP needs something more like an elbow method @desertnaut ?

Comment: It would be good not to leave ambiguities re ML/MLlib (the confusion already generated by Spark itself on this is enough): you refer to ML in your title, but the commands you use are evidently from MLlib. I kindly suggest to edit your title, replacing ML with MLlib

Comment: @eliasah not sure, maybe the OP can clarify on this...?